# pyomo matrix product

Tags: optimization, pyomo

I would like to use pyomo to solve a multiple linear regression under constraint in pyomo.
to do so I have 3 matrices :

- X (noted tour1 in the following code) My inputs (600x13)(bureaux*t1 in pyomo)
- Y (noted tour2 in the following code) the matrix I want to predict (600*3)(bureaux*t2 inpyomo)
- T (noted transfer In the code) (13x3)(t1*t2 in pyomo)

I would like to do the following

```
ypred = XT
minimize (ypred-y)**2
subject to 
0<T<1 
and Sum_i(Tij)=1
```

To that effect, I started the following code

```py
from pyomo.environ import * 

tour1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(60,13)),columns=["X"+str(i) for i in range(13)],index=["B"+str(i) for i in range(60)])
tour2=pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(60,3)),columns=["Y"+str(i) for i in range(3)],index=["B"+str(i) for i in range(60)])

def gettour1(model,i,j):
  return tour1.loc[i,j]

def gettour2(model,i,j):
  return tour2.loc[i,j]

def cost(model):
  return sum((sum(model.tour1[i,k] * model.transfer[k,j] for k in model.t1) - model.tour2[i,j] )**2 for i in model.bureaux for j in model.tour2)


model = ConcreteModel()
model.bureaux = Set(initialize=tour1.index.tolist())
model.t1 = Set(initialize=tour1.columns)
model.t2 = Set(initialize=tour2.columns)
model.tour1 = Param(model.bureaux, model.t1,initialize=gettour1)
model.tour2 = Param(model.bureaux, model.t2,initialize=gettour2)
model.transfer = Var(model.t1,model.t2,bounds=[0,1])
model.obj=Objective(rule=cost, sense=minimize)
```

I unfortunately get an error at this stage :

```
KeyError: "Index '('X0', 'B0', 'Y0')' is not valid for indexed component 'transfer'"
```

anyone knows how I can calculate the objective ?

furthermore any help for the constrains would be appreciated :-)

Comment: I would suggest to provide something reproducible (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things...

First, the error you are getting.  There is information in that error statement that should help identify the problem.  The construction appears to be trying to index `transfer` with a 3-part index `(x, b, y)`.  That clearly is outside of `t1 x t2`.  If you look at the sum equation you have, you are mistakenly using `model.tour2` instead of `model.t2`.

Also, your `bounds` parameter needs to be a tuple.

While building the model, you should be `pprint()`-ing the model very frequently to look for these types of issues.  That only works well if you have "small" data.  60 x 13 may be the normal problem size, but it is a total pain to troubleshoot.  So, start with something tiny, maybe 3 x 4.  Make a Set, `pprint()`.  Make a Constraint, `pprint()`...  Once the model computes/solves with "tiny" data, just pop in the real stuff.